# call to DELETE api does not work on Postman

Tags: c#, json, http, asp.net-web-api, postman

GET / POST / PUT, api calls work on Postman.

The vanilla Delete or custom delete do not.

**a. regular DELETE**

URL call in Postman - http://localhost:59510/api/Employee/123

ERROR in Postman -

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:59510/api/Employee/123'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Employee' that matches the request."
}
```

Code:

```
[HttpDelete]
public string Delete(int empID)
{
    try
    {
        string sSQL = $@"DELETE dbo.Employee WHERE emp_id='J-L12345M'";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (var connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAPIConn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connStr))
            {
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

            }
        }

        return "Deleted Successfully From EMPLOYEE table!!";
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Failed to Delete From EMPLOYEE table";
    }
}
```

**b. Custom Delete**

URL call in Postman - http://localhost:59510/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/123

Error In Postman - 404 error

```
[Route("api/Employee/DeleteEmployee")]
[HttpDelete]
public string DeleteEmployee(int empID)
{
    try
    {
        string sSQL = $@"DELETE dbo.Employee WHERE emp_id='{empID}'";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (var connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAPIConn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, connStr))
            {
                using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

            }
        }

        return "Deleted Successfully From EMPLOYEE table!!";
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Failed to Delete From EMPLOYEE table";
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried [Route("api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/{emdID}")]?

Comment: And if you put a route of `"api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/{empID}"` ?

Comment: Can you post your whole controller code?  Are you using DELETE verb in postman on the custom delete?  If you have a Route defined for the controller of "api/Employee" then the route on your method should just be "DeleteEmployee", otherwise the actual route of your custom delete method is "api/Employee/api/Employee/DeleteEmployee".

Comment: What if you try `api/Employee/DeleteEmployee?empID=123` ? Since you haven't specified that the empID is part of the route, it needs to be passed as a query parameter.

Comment: Note, don't do this: `string sSQL = $@"DELETE dbo.Employee WHERE emp_id='{empID}'";` especially if you one day make a controller that takes a `string empID` - http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: I think the issue is due to the attribute name. It should be id and not empId. If you want to use empId, make sure you use attribute routing and define the path match the variable name as above posters mentioned.

Comment: FWIW, the fact your URI contains the term "delete" implies that your URI design needs work :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `empID`  to route

```
[Route("api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/{empID}")]
[HttpDelete]
public string DeleteEmployee(int empID)
```

Comment: [Route("api/Employee/DeleteEmployee/{empID}")] did work.

Comment: Grad it worked for you.. you can mart this as an answer